# Plotting a smooth surface with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface

I am new to using the matplotlib module in Python, especially plotting 3D surfaces. I have generated a data matrix, where the data corresponds to the evaluation of

```
import numpy as np
z = np.linspace(0,3*np.pi,301)
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,201)
```

in the function sin(z)sin(x), that is to say

```
Y = np.sin(z).reshape((301,1))*np.sin(x).reshape((1,201))
```

I have managed to plot this surface using the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
mycmap = plt.get_cmap('gist_earth')
ax1.set_title('gist_earth color map')
surf1 = ax1.plot_surface(Z, X, Y.T, cmap=mycmap, rstride=2, cstride=2)
ax1.view_init(45, 45)
fig.colorbar(surf1, ax=ax1, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
```

The result shows as follow:

[image]

Then, I want to do the same but adding a random error term in the data matrix. To do so, the new matrix would be defined as

```
Y = np.sin(zsam).reshape((301,1))*np.sin(xsam).reshape((1,201)) + np.random.normal(0,0.25,301*201).reshape((301,201))
```

However, when I try to plot this matrix, I obtain this:

[image: enter code here]

How can I obtain a smooth surface as in the first case? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you have added noise to your data and plot includes that noise as well. What else do you expect?

Comment: But is there a way that the surface appears smoother?

Comment: Scale the noise you add by multiplying it with a factor? Still not smooth though because, as Roman said, you add noise.